# reshape 3D to 2D and back again in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, reshape

I have 3D data 64X148X2466 in which I would like to reshape into 2D: 9472X2466, do some operations on, and then bring the data back to the original 64X148X2466 array.  Everything I've tried mixes columns or rows up when I try to bring it back, for example:

```
y = reshape(Z,[],2466)';  
z = reshape(y, 64, 1484, 2466); %this mixes some of the columns up, and permute is unsatisfactory too.
```

For example, Z is a 3X4X2 array:

```
val(:,:,1) =

       -1643       -1233       -1613       -1828
       -1300       -1640       -1890       -1646
       -1426       -1773       -1379       -2089


val(:,:,2) =

       -1025       -1260       -1383       -1709
       -1553       -1241       -1450       -1882
       -1185       -1408        -741       -1620
```

y = reshape(Z,[],2)'; %gives me:

-1643   -1300   -1426   -1233   -1640   -1773   -1613   -1890   -1379   -1828   -1646   -2089

-1025   -1553   -1185   -1260   -1241   -1408   -1383   -1450   -741    -1709   -1882   -1620

%which is fine, but

z = reshape(y, 64, 1484, 2466); %which gives me:

val(:,:,1) =

```
   -1643       -1553       -1233       -1241
   -1025       -1426       -1260       -1773
   -1300       -1185       -1640       -1408
```

val(:,:,2) =

```
   -1613       -1450       -1828       -1882
   -1383       -1379       -1709       -2089
   -1890        -741       -1646       -1620
```

%which is not good.  I need the original array structure returned.

Comment: Why are you transposing the array to get `y`?

Comment: Exactly. You would need to undo the transpose first before the 2nd reshape. E.g., z = reshape(y', 64, 1484, 2466);

Comment: Or, don't transpose in the first place and you won't have the performance hit of transposing a large matrix twice.